# Location service running background after 10 min app was closed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location, cllocationmanager

My application in location service running background process working but after 10 min application was closed.I am using following steps are

1)added the key manually in .plist file

```
<key>Required background modes</key>
<array>
        <string>App registers for location updates</string>
</array>
```

2)Code is

```
 self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation    *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

   NSString *latVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *lonVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

}
```

I need to frequent update in background process without application close,please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` us this.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
locationManager.delegate = self;
```

This will ensure that your application is called even if it has been killed.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am implemented background service refer this link- http://developer.blueearth.net/2011/12/02/quick-tip-clearing-up-ios-multitasking/ . but it not working after 10 min application was killed,please help me

Comment: If any third party API in background location service?

Comment: It will be evoked once again when when location changes. Try to simulate a location change and see if it works for you.